# mod_rewrite: Use backreference from RewriteCond as CondPattern in another RewriteRule

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I try to use the first part of the fqdn as a rewrite target:

http://demo.dev.example.com/something => http://demo.dev.example.com/demo/something

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9-]+).dev.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://%1.dev.example.com/%1/$1 [P]
```

This creates an endless loop. So I need another condition that checks if this request is already rewritten or not:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/%1
```

Well this is not working, the documentation says nothing about using backreferences in CondPatterns, most possibly it's not supported.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/demo
```

This works perfectly, but isn't dynamic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution/Workaround: reserve one hostname part for internal requests:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^internal.dev.atizo.org [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([0-9a-z-]+).dev.atizo.org [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://internal.dev.atizo.org/%1/$1 [P]
```

Answer (score -2):

If you don't need to process any rules after the rewrite, just add the "L" = "last" option in the square brackets:

`RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://%1.dev.example.com/%1/$1 [P,L]`

Comment: Won't help. This is still doing endless loops.

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9-]+).dev.atizo.org [NC]
    RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://%1.dev.atizo.org/%1/$1 [P,L]